# css problem the text appear without spaces

Tags: css

i have a big problems in showing my codes
its appear as one text "not have spaces"
example

```
$paypal = new phpPayPal();
```

it will appear

[alt text http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/4531/65061412.gif](http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/4531/65061412.gif)

**[live example](http://bit.ly/51c0c0)**

[the css file 1](http://bit.ly/4H7ZSY)
[the css file 1](http://bit.ly/5S0E3j)

any my question is how to make with spaces
all this is in SyntaxHighlighter

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You don't see the spaces, because the content doesn't contain the spaces.  You could put a "padding-right: 10px;" on ".syntaxhighlighter code" around line 44 of core.css to give a similar effect.

Answer (score 1):

Are you developing the syntax highlighter or just using it?

If developing, you shouldn't trim spaces when splitting the tokens of the original code, instead just replace them with   so they are displayed in the output.

Cheers

Comment: i just useing it as it i did not made any modify

Answer (score 1):

Your highlighter is a flash file, and it has nothing to do with CSS or even javascript. You need to look in the flash code where it puts certain keywords in tags. It seems to also replace the following space character.

If it's not the flash file, you need to find the javascript that does this. I couldn't find it. CSS cannot remove characters, and it can't transform a non-tagged `pre` tag content into that detailed highlights.

Comment: Well I can't seem to find anywhere that it takes the code and transforms it to tags and css classes, so I have to assume that it's in the flash file. CSS itself cannot remove characters, and the input is correct, so the only option is javascript of flash. And I couldn't find a javascript file that did the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

David solution is very cool

```
padding-right: 5px !important;
```